# LaunchFileAsync fails when DisplayApplicationPicker=true

Tags: c#, uwp, fileopenpicker

I am new to UWP.

I am copying the `LaunchFileAsync` with `DisplayApplicationPicker` from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchfileasync#Windows_System_Launcher_LaunchFileAsync_Windows_Storage_IStorageFile_Windows_System_LauncherOptions_) to my project:

```
        string imageFile = @"test.pdf";
        var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(imageFile);

        if (file != null)
        {
            // Set the option to show the picker
            var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
            options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;

            // Launch the retrieved file
            bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);
            if (success)
            {
                // File launched
            }
            else
            {
                // File launch failed  ====> GETTING TO HERE
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Could not find file
        }
```

The return value is false.

Why?

BTW, calling `LaunchFileAsync(file)` (without the `options` argument) - opens the pdf file in Edge (my default PDF app).

Comment: Just checking: Are you calling from a UI thread?

Comment: Yes, this is simple dummy app.

Answer (score 0):

> LaunchFileAsync fails when DisplayApplicationPicker=true

I have tested above code, but we could not reproduce this issue. Please check if your pdf is build action is `Content` and tested the app in the latest OS version(1909).

> BTW, calling LaunchFileAsync(file) (without the options argument) - opens the pdf file in Edge (my default PDF app)

Edge is the default app that used to open pdf file. And you could edit it in Setting page.

**Setting -> Apps-> Default Apps-> Choose default apps by file type.**